# Having trouble when requesting with mustache and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, mustache

**What I'm trying to do:**

I made an alert function by spring which gives alert to user when the predetermined condition is fullfilled. This functions works well on Spring.
User can set several alerts on their own.
So when User presses "start alert" button in html, javascript sends get request using ajax depending on "idx" of alert on html.

**Problem :**

Seems like function is not working well on browser.
I did debug by using F12, I found out that Javascript is not getting any "idx" value..
So Nothing happens when I try to get alert.

All I wanna do is request by Alert id when button is pressed.

Here are my full code.

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/alerts/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public void AlertUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
    alertService.AlertUser(id);
}
```

**Service**

```
public void AlertUser(Long id) {

        Alert alert = alertRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException());

        double SetPrice = alert.getPrice();
         String ticker = alert.getTicker();

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        final NotificationRequest build = NotificationRequest.builder()
                .title(ticker + " alert")
                .message(SetPrice + "broke down")
                .token(notificationService.getToken(userDetailService.returnUser().getEmail()))
                .build();

        try {
            final WebsocketClientEndpoint clientEndPoint = new WebsocketClientEndpoint();

            Session session = clientEndPoint.connect(new URI("wss://ws.coincap.io/prices?assets=" + ticker));

            WebsocketClientEndpoint.MessageHandler handler = new WebsocketClientEndpoint.MessageHandler() {
                public void handleMessage(String message) throws ParseException, IOException {
                    Object obj = jsonParser.parse(message);

                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

                    double price = Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.get(ticker).toString());

                    System.out.println("가격 : " + price);

                    if (price < SetPrice) {
                        System.out.println("끝");
                        notificationService.sendNotification(build);
                        session.close();
                    }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        System.err.println("InterruptedException exception: " + ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            };
            clientEndPoint.addMessageHandler(handler);

        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            System.err.println("URISyntaxException exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**alert.mustache : {{#alerts}} ~ {{/alerts}} part is where problem occurs **

```
{{>layout/header}}

<form method="post" action="submitform" id="tickerSubmit">
    <select name="contact" id="contact">
        {{#tickers}}
            <option value="{{.}}">{{.}}</option>
        {{/tickers}}
    </select>
<!--    <button type="submit" name="submit">Choose Ticker</button>-->
</form>

<div>
    <input type="number" id = "price" placeholder="하한 금액을 입력하세요">
    <input type="number" id = "percentage" placeholder="하한 퍼센트를 입력하세요">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="alert-save-btn">알림 등록</button>
</div>

{{#alerts}} 
<tr>
    <div id = "idx">{{id}}</div>
    <td><input type="submit" value="알림시작" id="alert-start"/></td>
    <td>티커 : {{ticker}}</td>
    <td>가격 : {{price}}</td>
</tr>
{{/alerts}}

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app/notification.js"></script>

{{>layout/footer}}
```

**part of index.js encrypted in layout/footer**

```
$('#alert-start').on('click', function() {
                _this.alertStart();
            });
    },

    alertStart : function() {
        var idx = $('#idx').val();

         $.ajax({
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: '/alerts/'+idx,
                        }).done(function() {
                            alert('알림이 시작됩니다.');
                        }).fail(function (error) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify('이거' + error));
                        });
    },
```

Thanks in advance. any help or tip would be very helpful..

Comment: Hi , your `idx` is `div` tag not input element. So, to get value from that you can use `$('#idx').text()` . For more info please go through [docs](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: thanks, I think i should study more in jquery and html