# How can I use values in mustache loop at Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, mustache

It follows from the [previous question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74023226/having-trouble-when-requesting-with-mustache-and-javascript?noredirect=1#comment130700282_74023226)

**I want is  :**
I have alert List in server, and mustache showing it by loop (getting data from model)
All I want is to send different request based on alert id using jquery.
For example, GET alerts/1 | GET alerts/2 ......

But **Problem is that** only the "first" alert is chosen because "id" value is not chainging
in jquery.

**part of alert.mustache**

```
{{#alerts}} 
<tr name = "alerts">
    <input name = "idx" style="display : None" value="{{id}}">
    <td><input type="submit" value="알림시작" name="alert-start"/></td>
    <td>티커 : {{ticker}}</td>
    <td>가격 : {{price}}</td>
</tr>
{{/alerts}}
```

**part of index.js**

```
 $('input[name=alert-start]').on('click', function() { 
                _this.alertStart();
            });
    },

    alertStart : function() {
        var idx = $('input[name={{id}}]').val();

         $.ajax({
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: '/alerts/'+idx,
                        }).done(function() {
                            alert('알림이 시작됩니다.');
                        }).fail(function (error) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                        });
    },
```

I want that "var idx" changes when pressing different "alert-start".
I tried to use jquey each, but I'm a new to jquery, so having trouble on it...

Thanks in advance!!